# ASP.NET VB.NET Looping through similarly named form controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Ok, so I recently got some help from some  people on this form with learning how to loop through form controls with similar names in VB.Net. I am now working on converting this entire application over to a Web Application, and I am stuck in the same position. Could anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here. I know it must be something simple, but it is alluding me. I am attaching the code that works in VB.Net:

```
Public Conn As ADODB.Connection
Public Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public Sql As String

Public Sub ConnOpenClose()

    Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & databaseLocation & ""
    Conn.Open()
End Sub


ConnOpenClose()

Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Sql = "SELECT * FROM INVOICES WHERE CurrentStatus<>'Checked-Out' ORDER BY INVOICES.CurrentStatusNum, INVOICES.OpenedDate,OpenedTime;"
SortCategory = ""
Rs.Open(Sql, Conn)
If Rs.EOF = False Then
    Rs.Move(moveIndex)
    For a = 1 To 20
        If Rs.EOF = True Then
            Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = ""
            Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Visible = False
            Me.Controls("lblInvoice" & a).Text = ""
            Me.Controls("lblInvoice" & a).Visible = False
            Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Text = ""
            Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Visible = False
            cmdScrollDown.Enabled = False
        Else
            If SortCategory <> Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value Then
                SortCategory = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value
                tempInteger = a
                If Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value = "Checked In" Then
                    Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value & " - Total: " & Me.Controls("lblCheckedIn").Text
                ElseIf Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value = "On Bench" Then
                    Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value & " - Total: " & Me.Controls("lblOnBench").Text
                ElseIf Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value = "Update" Then
                    Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value & " - Total: " & Me.Controls("lblUpdate").Text
                ElseIf Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value = "Contact Us" Then
                    Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value & " - Total: " & Me.Controls("lblContactUs").Text
                ElseIf Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value = "Finished" Then
                    Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value & " - Total: " & Me.Controls("lblFinished").Text
                ElseIf Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value = "To Be Scrapped" Then
                    Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value & " - Total: " & Me.Controls("lblToBeScrapped").Text
                Else
                    Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value
                End If
                Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Visible = True
                Me.Controls("lblInvoice" & a).Text = ""
                Me.Controls("lblInvoice" & a).Visible = False
                Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Text = ""
                Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Visible = False
            Else
                Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("CurrentStatus").Value
                Me.Controls("lblStatus" & a).Visible = False
                Me.Controls("lblInvoice" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("InvoiceID").Value & " - " & Rs.Fields("CustomerFName").Value & " " & Rs.Fields("CustomerLName").Value & " (" & DateDiff("d", Rs.Fields("OpenedDate").Value, Now()) & " days)"
                Me.Controls("lblInvoice" & a).Visible = True
                If Rs.Fields("LastStopSystem").Value = True Then
                    If Rs.Fields("ReturningSystem").Value = True Then
                        Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Text = "LS - " & Rs.Fields("TypeOfSystem").Value & " - " & Rs.Fields("SystemMakeModel").Value & " RETURN"
                        Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).ForeColor = Color.Red
                    Else
                        Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Text = "LS - " & Rs.Fields("TypeOfSystem").Value & " - " & Rs.Fields("SystemMakeModel").Value
                        Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
                    End If
                    Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Visible = True
                    Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Font = New Font(Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                Else
                    If Rs.Fields("ReturningSystem").Value = True Then
                        Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("TypeOfSystem").Value & " - " & Rs.Fields("SystemMakeModel").Value & " RETURN"
                        Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).ForeColor = Color.Red
                    Else
                        Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Text = Rs.Fields("TypeOfSystem").Value & " - " & Rs.Fields("SystemMakeModel").Value
                        Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).ForeColor = Color.Black
                    End If
                    Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Visible = True
                    Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Font = New Font(Me.Controls("lblSystemMakeModel" & a).Font, FontStyle.Regular)
                End If
                Rs.MoveNext()
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Rs.EOF = False Then cmdScrollDown.Enabled = True
End If
```

Here is what I have so far, and in some regards it is working, but I cannot get the loop through form elements to work. Please help me.

```
Public Conn As OleDbConnection
Public Rs As OleDbDataAdapter
Public DS As New DataSet
Public Sql As String
Public oControl As Label

Public Sub ConnOpenClose()
  'If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Conn.Close()
  Conn = New OleDbConnection
  Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=C:\inetpub\CompTracking.mdb"
  Conn.Open()
End Sub

Public Function FindAControl(ByVal controls As ControlCollection, ByVal toFind As String) As Control

  If controls IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each oControl As Control In controls
      If oControl.ID.Equals(toFind, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        Return oControl
      ElseIf oControl.HasControls Then
        Dim oFoundControl As Control

        oFoundControl = FindAControl(oControl.Controls, toFind)
        If oFoundControl IsNot Nothing Then
          Return oFoundControl
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End If

  Return Nothing
End Function


Public Sub RefreshItems()
  lblCheckedIn.Text = "0"
  lblOnBench.Text = "0"
  lblUpdate.Text = "0"
  lblContactUs.Text = "0"
  lblFinished.Text = "0"
  lblToBeScrapped.Text = "0"
  lblLastStop.Text = "0"
  lblReturns.Text = "0"

  moveIndex = 0

  ConnOpenClose()

  Sql = "SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE CurrentStatus<>'Checked-Out' ORDER BY INVOICES.CurrentStatusNum, INVOICES.OpenedDate,OpenedTime"
  Rs = New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, Conn)
  Rs.Fill(DS, "Invoices")

  For i = 0 To DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows.Count - 1
    If DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(i).Item("CurrentStatus") = "Checked In" Then
      lblCheckedIn.Text = Convert.ToInt16(lblCheckedIn.Text) + 1
    ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(i).Item("CurrentStatus") = "On Bench" Then
      lblOnBench.Text = Convert.ToInt16(lblOnBench.Text) + 1
    ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(i).Item("CurrentStatus") = "Update" Then
      lblUpdate.Text = Convert.ToInt16(lblUpdate.Text) + 1
    ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(i).Item("CurrentStatus") = "Contact Us" Then
      lblContactUs.Text = Convert.ToInt16(lblContactUs.Text) + 1
    ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(i).Item("CurrentStatus") = "To Be Scrapped" Then
      lblToBeScrapped.Text = Convert.ToInt16(lblToBeScrapped.Text) + 1
    ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(i).Item("CurrentStatus") = "Finished" Then
      lblFinished.Text = Convert.ToInt16(lblFinished.Text) + 1
    End If
    If DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(i).Item("LastStopSystem") = True Then
      lblLastStop.Text = Convert.ToInt16(lblLastStop.Text) + 1
    End If
    If DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(i).Item("ReturningSystem") = True Then
      lblReturns.Text = Convert.ToInt16(lblReturns.Text) + 1
    End If
  Next

  lblTotalCheckedIn.Text = "Checked In: " & lblCheckedIn.Text
  lblTotalOnBench.Text = "On Bench: " & lblOnBench.Text
  lblTotalUpdate.Text = "Update: " & lblUpdate.Text
  lblTotalContactUs.Text = "Contact Us: " & lblContactUs.Text
  lblTotalToBeScrapped.Text = "To Be Scrapped: " & lblToBeScrapped.Text
  lblTotalFinished.Text = "Finished: " & lblFinished.Text
  lblTotalLastStop.Text = "LS Systems: " & lblLastStop.Text
  lblTotalReturns.Text = "Returns: " & lblReturns.Text

  ConnOpenClose()

  Sql = "SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE CurrentStatus<>'Checked-Out' ORDER BY INVOICES.CurrentStatusNum, INVOICES.OpenedDate,OpenedTime"
  SortCategory = ""
  Rs = New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, Conn)
  Rs.Fill(DS, "Invoices")
  For a = 1 To 20
    If ((a - 1) + moveIndex) > (DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows.Count - 1) Then
      'exceeds total number of records, display blank fields
      oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
      If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
      If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
      oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblInvoice" & a), Label)
      If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
      If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
      oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblSystemMakeModel" & a), Label)
      If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
      If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
      cmdScrollDown.Enabled = False
    Else
      If sortCategory <> DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus") Then
        sortCategory = DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus")
        If DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus") = "Checked In" Then
          oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = "Checked In - Total: " & lblTotalCheckedIn.Text
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus") = "On Bench" Then
          oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = "On Bench - Total: " & lblTotalOnBench.Text
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus") = "Update" Then
          oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = "Update - Total: " & lblTotalUpdate.Text
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus") = "Contact Us" Then
          oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = "Contact Us - Total: " & lblTotalContactUs.Text
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus") = "To Be Scrapped" Then
          oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = "To Be Scrapped - Total: " & lblTotalToBeScrapped.Text
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        ElseIf DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus") = "Finished" Then
          oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = "Finished - Total: " & lblTotalFinished.Text
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        Else
          oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus")
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        End If
        oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblInvoice" & a), Label)
        If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
        If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblSystemMakeModel" & a), Label)
        If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
        If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
      Else
        oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
        If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CurrentStatus")
        If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = False
        oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblInvoice" & a), Label)
        If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("InvoiceID") & " - " & DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CustomerFName") & " " & DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("CustomerLName") & " (" & DateDiff("d", DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("OpenedDate"), Now()) & " days)"
        If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = True
        oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblSystemMakeModel" & a), Label)
        If DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("LastStopSystem") = True Then
          If DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("ReturningSystem") = True Then
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
          Else
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkGreen
          End If
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = True
        Else
          If DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows(a + moveIndex).Item("ReturningSystem") = True Then
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
          Else
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = ""
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
          End If
          If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = True
        End If
        'Rs.movenext
      End If
    End If
  Next
  If (19 + moveIndex) > (DS.Tables("Invoices").Rows.Count - 1) Then cmdScrollDown.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh the stored procedure in the database named "sp_SB-Invoices" is this SQL statement: SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE CurrentStatus<>'Checked-Out' ORDER BY INVOICES.CurrentStatusNum, INVOICES.OpenedDate,OpenedTime WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION;

Answer (score 1):

What you need first is a recursive method to find the specific control in the form's controls collection:

```
Private Function FindAControl(ByVal controls As ControlCollection, ByVal toFind As String) As Control

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(toFind) Then
       Throw New ArgumentException("toFind is null or empty")
    End If

    If controls IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each oControl As Control In controls
            If oControl IsNot Nothing Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oControl.ID) AndAlso oControl.ID.Equals(toFind, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                    Return oControl
                ElseIf oControl.HasControls Then
                    Dim oFoundControl As Control

                    oFoundControl = FindAControl(oControl.Controls, toFind)
                    If oFoundControl IsNot Nothing Then
                        Return oFoundControl
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

You can call this as:

```
Dim oControl As Label
oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label)
If oControl IsNot Nothing Then
    oControl.Text = ""
End If
```

Comment: I am getting a warning on that function you wrote, it is giving me a squiggly line under oFoundControl.Controls, on line 9, with the warning "Variable oFoundControl' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."  -- When I compile and run it, I get an error at line 4, NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. How can this be fixed. The function is being called in this matter: TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label).Text = ""

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in the code. I've fixed the answer, but you can change the underlined name to `oControl`.

Comment: Okay, the squiggly line is now gone, but on compile and running, it is throwing another error at If oControl.ID.Equals(toFind, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then .   -- The error is again the "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" Any other ideas?

Comment: It is stating "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", it is suggesting use the "new" keyword to create an object instance.

Comment: That's very, very strange. I can only think of two reasons for this: 1) toFind is nothing (I have updated the answer to throw a different exception if this is the case); 2) For some unknown reason, control is nothing (I can't think how this would be but I have added a case for it in the answer).

Comment: I did a step through on the script, and it throws the error when it first enters the function. I have verified that toFind is equal to lblStatus1, which is what it is suppose to be. Does that help?

Comment: I checked oControl.ID and it is returning Nothing (not what it is suppose to be I assume).

Comment: Does it throw the argument exception (tofind is null)? I wonder if there is a control in there without an ID? I don't think asp.net allows this, but that's the only other thing I can think of. Updated answer with check for that.

Comment: Well the controls that I checked are oControl and toFind. oControl is being set like this: oControl = TryCast(FindAControl(Me.Controls, "lblStatus" & a), Label). However once it gets to the function, it errors out, I do an ?oControl in the Immediate window and it returns Nothing, and toFind returns lblStatus1. It throws the error before it starts processing the function. (IE, when stepping through the code, I get to the statement that calls the function and then it goes to the function and then gives me the NullReferenceException.

Comment: ok, that helps narrow it down. 2 more things to check on the line that calls the function: 1) What is the value of a, 2) Is Me.Controls valid?

Comment: The value of a is 1, when it gets passed into the function as toFind it becomes lblStatus1 (which is what it is suppose to be.). -- Right before the call to the function I do a check on Me.Controls I get this from the Immediate Window: ?Me.Controls
{System.Web.UI.ControlCollection}
    Count: &H5
    IsReadOnly: False
    IsSynchronized: False
    Item: In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.
    Owner: {ASP.site_master}
    SyncRoot: {System.Web.UI.ControlCollection}

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what else to suggest. I've tried this here and it works correctly. You can try adding Option Explicit On and Option Strict On to the to top of the page to see if there are any conflicts. Otherwise, I am completely stumped, which doesn't happen too often.

Comment: Might this be causing some problems because this is being executed from the Site.Master file?

Comment: I ended up solving my problem by using the following code: `code` oControl = Page.Master.FindControl("lblStatus" & a)
If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Text = "some text"
If oControl IsNot Nothing Then oControl.Visible = True `code`